# What is this silver and transparent green electronic piece for / from

Tags: part-identification, piece-information, electronics, remote-control

I found this Lego in a box with other old Lego parts and I have no idea what it is for. It has a 'Lego' logo with a code `5202` but I can not find anything online.

Could someone please give me more info on this?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is a [Spybotics Module](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4232#T=C) from set [3809-1 Technojaw T55](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=3809-1#T=S&O=%7B%7D).

[image]